# Hive building animals

Tags: behaviour

Many species of animals build *nests* to live in. However, a bee*hive* is a structure built by *Homo sapians* that houses *Apis mellifera* (or a related bee species). Are there other species of animals that build hives, i.e. that build structures designed to house a species *different* than their own.

Comment: Not specifically to nest other species, but I know there are ant species who colonies the nests of other species of ants e.g. [Dino ants in Brazil](http://periodicos.uefs.br/index.php/sociobiology/article/view/1251).

Comment: Probably not in the spirit of the question, but there are species of ants that farm fungi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is called [metabiosis](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/metabiosis):

> a mode of living in which one organism is dependent on another for
> preparation of an environment in which it can live.

**Examples:**

The Goby and the Pistol shrimp. [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YFKdjtLozc&t=20s)

The video shows these housemates cooperating, the goby, with its capable vision keeping watch, the shrimp, pushing sand and detritus from the shared burrow. This extends to keeping watch whilst the goby feeds - waggling and snapping it's claws as a warning if a potential predator shows, the goby bringing back food to the burrow, the shrimp eating the leftovers. In times of hardship the shrimp will eat the bodily waste of the fish.

[Hermit crabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermit_crab):

Their non-calcified abdomen makes their adoption of a marine snail-shell obligatory. As time goes by, with growth, they will seek-out a bigger or more suitable home, competing and combatting (rather carefully not to expose their vulnerable parts) until a compromise is found - usually on the terms set by the largest or fiercest crab present ([youtube video BBC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpjklLt1qWk)).

[The dresser crab](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn27702-zoologger-decorator-crabs-accessorise-to-avoid-being-eaten/) (decorator crab) (But this is stretching the definition a little):

[image: Crab with a sea-urchin hat.]

<sup>newscientist.com 2015 Fair usage</sup>

These decapods show discretion, camouflaging their appearance with whatever is around, sea anemones, weed, a sea urchin as above or increasingly, human made detritus ([youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FS78u5flllY)). Using their spikey shell to immobilise their covering. Though in this case there is no strict dependance, the anemone is thought to benefit by food particles being stirred-up by the crab during feeding and passage.

Comment: The goby+shrimp is the best example. The snails unwittingly give their shells up to the hermit crabs when they die, so it is not an "intentional" act on the part of the snails.